# Why isn't Bootstrap mobile nav button expanding nav?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The website is [AudioTalks](http://audiotalks.org)

Code for the navbar located below. When I load the site on mobile and click the button to drop down the navigation the button becomes darker and stays darker (stays depressed) and no navbar links drop down. The button becomes darker and that's it.

Appreciate any help I can get.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="navbar-brand">Audio Talks</div>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="legal.html">Legal</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is not loading on your page. Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. Load jQuery before `bootstrap.min.js`.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Ideally you'd load your scripts in the footer of your website for better all around performance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be as simple as adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` ? I added it (to index only) but there is no change.

Comment: Add it **before** Bootstrap's JavaScript file.

Comment: All pages except for the legal page now work but legal doesn't seem to differ at all from the about page code wise.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but for some reason you are including jQuery a second time in the footer of your site.